# php array_diff with before and after array

Tags: php, arrays, diff

someone know a function how to get before and after things of array_diff.

```
var_dump(array_diff(['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'x'], ['a' => 'c', 'c' => 'x']));
```

Result is

```
array(1) {
  'a' =>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

And i want something like

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'a' =>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    'a' =>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

Is there a function for that or have you some snippet for it?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) - array_diff only compares values.

You could do something like this:

```
$arr1 = ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'x'];
$arr2 = ['a' => 'c', 'c' => 'x'];

$diffs = [
    array_diff_assoc($arr1, $arr2),
    array_diff_assoc($arr2, $arr1)
];
```

Comment: Ah thanks but i see that it not work with array in array. (Recursive diff)
But i think i saw a recursive array_diff last days. Or do you have a solution for that? I mean that was something with array_map.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: You can diffirentiate there keys because after your array are keys of arrays

```
 $newArr = [
  ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'x'],
  ['a' => 'c', 'c' => 'x']
 ];

$a = array_diff_assoc($newArr[0], $newArr[1]); //differentiate the 1st and 2nd keys
$b = array_diff_assoc($newArr[1], $newArr[0]); //differentiate the 2nd keys to the 1st keys
$diff = [$a, $b]; //then store the result to an array

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($diff);
```

Here's the output:

```
 array(2) {
   [0]=>
    array(1) {
     ["a"]=>
     string(1) "b"
    }
   [1]=>
    array(1) {
     ["a"]=>
     string(1) "c"
   }
 }
```

Or if it is a array of array:

```
 //all keys are 0 and 1 because you're differentiate only two keys in one multi-dimensional array

$arr2= [
   0 => [
     ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'x'],
     ['a' => 'c', 'c' => 'x']
   ],
   1 => [
     ['d' => 'e', 'c' => 'y'],
     ['d' => 'b', 'c' => 'y']
   ]
];

foreach($arr2 as $key => $val){
  $a[] = array_diff_assoc($val[0], $val[1]);
  $b[] = array_diff_assoc($val[1], $val[0]);
 }
 var_dump($diff);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
     array(1) {
       ["a"]=>
       string(1) "b"
     }
    [1]=>
     array(1) {
      ["d"]=>
      string(1) "e"
     }
    }
  [1]=>
    array(2) {
     [0]=>
      array(1) {
       ["a"]=>
       string(1) "c"
      }
     [1]=>
      array(1) {
       ["d"]=>
       string(1) "b"
      }
   }
}
```